# What is the mean amount (in grams) of dissolved carbon in a ton of sea water?

Tags: ocean-models

What is the mean amount (in grams) of dissolved carbon in a ton of sea water ?

1. The value I want is the concentration value in say the first two metres of surface water (A distribution of this concentration by depth would also help)
2. If I take say the 10% surface area where the CO<sub>2</sub> concentration is the highest on the globe, what does it change about the result ?

Please feel free to answer even if your answer is not the complete one but just part of it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This graph at Wikipedia/Wikimedia is part of the answer :

[image]

source:

- [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_carbon_cycle#/media/File:WOA05_GLODAP_pd_DIC_AYool.png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_carbon_cycle#/media/File:WOA05_GLODAP_pd_DIC_AYool.png)
- [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WOA05_GLODAP_pd_DIC_AYool.png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WOA05_GLODAP_pd_DIC_AYool.png)

2.15 mol/m<sup>3</sup> at the surface in 1990 seems like a approximative value, which makes approximately 27 g.

Now, the two questions left are:

- How did this value evolve since 1990?
- Does this concentration change a lot with depth?